# ModuleMirror of scala object defined via ToolBox

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I am attempting to define a Scala object by providing a string to ToolBox, but I cannot find a way to get a handle to the resulting ModuleMirror. I imagine it would be something like the following but I don't seem able to get the RuntimeClass from the result of the ToolBox eval:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val src = """ object MyObject { def hello() = "world" } """

val mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val toolBox = mirror.mkToolBox()
val tree = toolBox.parse(src)
val value = toolBox.eval(tree)

// convert from result of eval to RuntimeClass...?
val runtimeClass: RuntimeClass = ???

val moduleSymbol = mirror.moduleSymbol(runtimeClass)

val moduleMirror = mirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol.asModule)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get a class of the object would probably be returning `MyObject.getClass` from the block of code being compiled.

However, calling `moduleSymbol` on the resulting class would result in `NoSymbol`, because local objects aren't currently supported by Scala reflection. Why local objects? Because `eval` wraps the code fed to it in a method to enable its evaluation, which means that `MyObject` would end up being local to the wrapper method. Why aren't currently supported? Well, it's because Scala reflection relies on `@ScalaSignature` annotations that carry Scala-specific metadata, and these annotations are currently not saved for local definitions.

I think it would be possible to change `ToolBox.compile` (a non-evaluating counterpart of `eval`) to special-case processing of top-level definitions, so that they not end up being compiled as local. Could you submit an issue to our issue tracker, so that we don't forget to fix it?

Comment: I added the issue (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8174) in what I think was the correct place. Thanks for your insightful answer!

Comment: Haha! I knew I've already faced this bug before, but I definitely didn't remember that I've already submitted a pull request: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2662. Going to revive it now :)